# Use tables prefix for spatie/laravel-tags tables

Tags: laravel-5, tags

In my Laravel 5.7 app, I use `spatie/laravel-tags: ^2.1`. I need to use a prefix for table names and I set table property of any model with prefix and with empty prefix property in `config/database.php`. It works for my model, except the tag model,
when I use method `findOrCreate` from `Spatie\Tags\Tag`.

I got error that table “tags” not found, as my prefix is not set.
If there is a way to set this prefix(config options?) ?
sure decision without modifications of `vendor/spatie/laravel-tags/src/Tag.php` file preferable...

Thanks!

Comment: still not resolved. Same here

Answer (score 0):

You can set the prefix for the tag table by modifying the config/database.php file. Under the connections array, find the connection that you're using (usually mysql), and add the prefix key with your desired prefix value. Here's an example:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        // ... other config options ...
        'prefix' => 'my_prefix_',
    ],
],
```

This will set the prefix for all tables under this connection, including the tags table used by `spatie/laravel-tags`.

If you need to set a different prefix for the tags table specifically, you can add a new key called tags under the prefix key, like this:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        // ... other config options ...
        'prefix' => [
            'default' => 'my_prefix_',
            'tags' => 'my_tags_prefix_',
        ],
    ],
],
```

This will set the prefix for all tables except for the tags table, which will use the my_tags_prefix_ prefix.

After making this change, make sure to clear the Laravel cache using the `php artisan cache:clear` command, so that the configuration changes are applied.